# Tmux restore creates an empty session

Tags: shell, tmux

I'm using the `tmux-continuum` and `tmux-resurrect` plugins. If I kill tmux (restarting my machine for example) and then run the following commands:

```
$ tmux ls
$ failed to connect to server: No such file or directory
```

Then when I start tmux it automatically restores my saved sessions **plus** an unnamed session (usually `0`)

```
$ tmux
$ tmux ls
  0: 1 windows (created...)
  saved_session_1: 1 windows (created...)
  saved_session_2: 1 windows (created...)
  ...
```

My current workflow goes like this:

- Start `tmux`
- Detach from `tmux`
- Attach to the unnamed session
- Kill unnamed session
- Attach to one of my saved sessions

I don't want to have to repeat this every time I restart tmux. How can I restore my saved tmux sessions without creating the unnamed session?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your question this is a [common issue](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/issues/101) with `tmux-resurrect`. The solution given [here](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/issues/101#issuecomment-560026971) (currently the last comment in the Github discussion) has worked for me.

Add the following to your `.tmux.conf` and then do `source ~.tmux.conf`(if that is the path of your conf file):

```
set -g @resurrect-hook-pre-restore-pane-processes 'tmux switch-client -n && tmux kill-session -t=0'
```

This a [hook](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tmux.1.html#hooks) for `tmux-resurrect` which tells it to kill session 0 before restoring the panels.

Note: since the name of the session (`-t=0`) is hardcoded it will work only for that session, hence only if you do restore when you start the tmux server the first time, if you restore from sessions after 0 nothing will happen (which is nice to avoid kill sessions accidentally).

Comment: It seems like this was fixed a month ago, but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command (preferably make an alias it):

```
$ tmux new-session -A -s [session-name]
```

Flag meaning:

```
-s refers to session name.
-A In case session-name exists, command will act like attach-session instead of new-session.
```

Refer to the man page for official documentation:

```
$ man tmux

new-session [-AdDEP] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t
        target-session] [-x width] [-y height] [shell-command]
              (alias: new)
        Create a new session with name session-name.

        The new session is attached to the current terminal unless -d is given.  window-name and
        shell-command are the name of and shell command to execute in the initial window.  If -d
        is used, -x and -y specify the size of the initial window (80 by 24 if not given).

        If run from a terminal, any termios(4) special characters are saved and used for new win‐
        dows in the new session.

        The -A flag makes new-session behave like attach-session if session-name already exists;
        in this case, -D behaves like -d to attach-session.

        If -t is given, the new session is grouped with target-session.  This means they share
        the same set of windows - all windows from target-session are linked to the new session,
        any new windows are linked to both sessions and any windows closed removed from both ses‐
        sions.  The current and previous window and any session options remain independent and
        either session may be killed without affecting the other.  -n and shell-command are
        invalid if -t is used.

        The -P option prints information about the new session after it has been created.  By
        default, it uses the format ‘#{session_name}:’ but a different format may be specified
        with -F.

        If -E is used, the update-environment option will not be applied.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply launch tmux by `tmux a` (i.e. attach to "existing" sessions). This would trigger tmux-continuum to first restore all sessions and then you'll get attached to one of them.

Works fine for me. I'm running tmux 3.0a with tmux-resurrect and tmux-continuum plugins.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says that it can't attach or something.